# Cannot write long output to file

Tags: output

I'm a beginner. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04

I am trying to send the output from a command that installs dependencies for a subsequent install command.

I have tried:

```
$ my_command > output.txt
$ my_command >> output.txt
$ my_command | tee output.txt
```

I always just get the last, maybe, one hundred lines of output. I am loosing some lines of output because I watch them scroll by on the terminal. I might be loosing a few hundred lines of output. I have searched the Internet and can't find much except to install   xfce4-terminal  which I do not want to try because I am worried about losing my existing desktop.

I am assuming that xfce4-terminal must be interacting with command lines, but what are they?

Thank you for any assistance in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that `my_command` is writing exclusively to the standard output stream, or is it possible that some lines are being written to the standard error stream? If you want to capture the latter as well, use `> output.txt 2>&1` or (in bash) `&> output.txt`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing append flag for `tee`, see `man tee` locally or [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/tee.1.html):

> **tee** [OPTION]... [FILE]...
> Copy standard input to each FILE, and also to standard output.
>
> **-a**, **--append**
> append to the given FILEs, do not overwrite

Correct command sequence would be:

```
my_command > output.txt
my_command >> output.txt
my_command | tee -a output.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Unfortunately the command that was generating hundreds of lines of output (a pip3 command to install multiple dependencies) is for some unknown reason not now doing so. So, I can't try the suggestions out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what finally worked for me:

```
~$script output_1.txt  
~$<command>
~$exit
```